# Trouble with rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm attempting to link two models together with `has_many` and `belongs_to` along with using rails3-jquery-autocomplete, but I cannot seem to get it to pull any data from the `vocab` table.

I am trying to autocomplete the 'skills' field with data from 'vocab' table. I can submit skills just fine and they save properly in the 'skills' table, the autocomplete is the only thing troubling me.

I would appreciate **any** help. I condensed my code to relevant code only. As a note, I do have the plugin installed properly, html is outputting the proper JS and input tags.

Thanks in advance :) Any help is greatly appreciated.

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

autocomplete :vocab, :name

  def new
    @user = User.new
    3.times do
        skill = @user.skills.build
    end
  end

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
    has_many :skills, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills       
end
```

**skill.rb**

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :skills do |builder| %>
    <%= render "skill_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_skill_fields.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <%=f.label :skill_name, "Skill" %>
  <%=f.autocomplete_field :skill_name, users_autocomplete_vocab_name_path %>
</p>
```

**routes.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/autocomplete_vocab_name'
end
```

**Database**

```
user
  -id

skills
  -user_id
  -skill_name

vocab
  -name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as an idea .. :

in your code, it looks like you have multiple autocomplete fields :

```
<%=f.autocomplete_field :skill_name, users_autocomplete_vocab_name_path %>
```

if these fields all have the same html 'id' and 'name' attributes ( which is most likely happening ), js might not be able to get the field you want.

So, just to clarify :
1. In your server log, do you see that request actually reaches your controller? (users_autocomplete_vocab_name_path)
2. Anything changes if you leave just one autocomplete field in your view?

Just a small note. If you have less then 100-200 of skills in your app, you could output all these as json to some hidden div, parse it with jquery and make autocompletion work locally. It will work faster and you'll avoid extra requests to your web server and database. I had to implement the same functionality some time ago ( autocomplete user's friends names ). I've made it so that if user has less then 250 friends - autocomplete locally, else - autocomplete from server. Btw, I've used jquery-ui autocomplete, really nice thing if you like javascript :)

Comment: Thanks, Vlad -- I'll give this a try. Unfortunately, we will be having over 10,000 entries so local isn't an option :/

Comment: Turns out, I am an idiot. I was using a corrupt jQuery file. Bleh.